# Why i am getting 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0' when i am fetch?

Tags: reactjs, syntax, fetch

Here's my code:

```html
const onSubmit = async (value) => {
        try{
            const response = await fetch(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${value.city}&appid=${KEY}`);
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data)
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
```

Why i am getting 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0'?

Comment: Because the response isn't JSON. Look in the browser's network tab to see what it returns, and specifically where it sends the request – you're missing the `https://` part of the URL.

Comment: ... I wasted time only cuz of 'http' fragment in url xd Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should add `https://` to the URL:

```
const onSubmit = async (value) => {
        try{
            const response = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${value.city}&appid=${KEY}`);
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data)
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
```